# Active Records Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, simple-form

In my webapp I have a model that contains an attribute which is a array of ints. Each int as a meaning, so I'm using a enum. But it seems that my approach to the problem is not working:

I have the following model:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum someenum:      [:abc, :def, :ghi]
end
```

In the database:

```
class CreateAs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  t.integer :someenum, array: true, default: []
end
```

And in the view I have something like this:

```
f.input :someenum, collection: A.someenums, as: :check_boxes
```

Which returns something like `['0', '1', '']`.
But when I'm creating an instance of A I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: '['0', '1', '']' is not a valid someenum
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
f.input :someenum, collection: A.someenums, as: :check_boxes
```

to

```
f.input :someenum, collection: A.someenums.keys.to_a, as: :check_boxes
```

Comment: Still not working. The error is: ArgumentError ('["abc", "def", ""]' is not a valid someenum)

Comment: @luis.alves Can you inspect and post the HTML generated?

Comment: I fixed the problem, actually it's because the array has the same name as the enum. And therefore rails assumes your trying to populate an attribute that is an enum.

Comment: @luis.alves Glad you figured it out. Anyways if you find my answer helpful please accept it :)